# Is there any way to differentiate "Normal Purchase" from "Promo code purchase"?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, promotion-code

I have InApp products for my android app. When an InApp Product is purchased, I will be checking for

1. Purchase bundle of product ID - which tells the purchase is successful.
2. developerPayload validation - which tells the purchase data recieved is valid.

So far InApp Purchases made in my app are well working since I'm recieving matched purchase bundle as well matched paylaod.

When the purchase is via promo code,

1. I'm recieving matched purchase bundle for InApp Product
2. Empty developerPayload.

Since I'm having the above two checks for every InApp Prodcut, verification is failed at validating developers payload.

After some research I came to know that,

When a promo code is used for an in-app purchase (the PURCHASES_UPDATED intent) it will completely bypass the purchase flow so the app can't supply an "developerPayload", used for remote verification.

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/7

1. If it is a promo code purchase, Can't I receive "developerPayload"?
2. If ans is NOT to the question (1), is there any way to differentiate if a purchase is happend as a "Normal" or "Promo code" purchase?
3. If ans is NOT to the question (2), should I skip check for validating developerPayload? , If there is a way to differentiate, what is that?
4. What is the way google is providing to skip developers payload if it is a promo code purchase?